# drawbacks using React.Children on a non-react-element array?

Tags: reactjs

It is well known that when building an array of components the developer needs to add the `key` prop to any children:

```
render () {
  let children = someArray.map((x, i) => {
    return <div>{x}</div>
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

This will result in the warning `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`

But if you do the same thing and use `React.Children.map`, you don't need to add the key prop:

```
render () {
  let children = React.Children.map(someArray, (x, i) => {
    return <div>{x}</div>
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

What I'm wondering is: is there anything to be wary about using the second method here?

Comment: Not sure what happens under the hood, but having a key for your items is good for you. It prevents surprising effects of reconciliation, so why would you *not* do it?

Comment: The React docs states that `React.Children.map` takes a `child object` as first argument. Why would you want to use the API in a non-standard way just so you can avoid adding a standard property?

Comment: I should explain that I'm not arguing against setting the key prop, it is an important part of React for sure. Even setting the key to an items index in the list sometimes isn't enough. This case came up when blindly using the index from `map` as the key, as the list items had no concrete ids. I wondered if passing through `React.Children` would: A) Safe check what you pass and B) Automatically set the key to the items index.

Comment: @David the signature `React.Children.map(object children, function fn [, object context])` tells me that it takes any object as children, as opposed to something like `React.Children.map(ReactElement[] children, function fn [, object context])`, maybe we read that differently